# Suitelet of netsuite not running

Tags: javascript, netsuite

```
function demoHTML(request, response)
{
    var html =  ' <html> <body> <h1>Hello World</h1> </body> </html>';
    response.write( html ); 
   //prefix header with Custom-Header. See nlobjResponse.setHeader(name, value)
    response.setHeader('Custom-Header-Demo', 'Demo');
}
```

After deploying the Script the following error is coming...

**ERROR**

`You are not allowed to navigate directly to this page`

Comment: Make sure that the Select All check box has been selected on the Audience tab of the Script Deployment page.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, make sure the Status is set to "Released".

Answer (score 1):

As @Rockstar stated, check the *Audience* tab on your Script Deployment. Make sure that the applicable Roles or Employees are allowed to access the page, and make sure that the user/role that you are using have access as well. By default, no permissions are given to anyone on the Deployment.

Comment: After doin the said thing....the error page is not coming but a blank page is coming....and its loading......is there a problem with the code?

Comment: I actually don't see a problem with the code right off the top of my head. Now you may want to use the Dev Tools in whichever browser you are using to monitor the error logs and Network requests to see where failures are happening. If you are getting a blank page, then you at least know the permissions are working.

Comment: I just tested by making a brand new Suitelet then copying and pasting your exact code into it. I get Hello, World as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was updating the scripts via advanced add in file Cabinet -- using overwrite existing files

I had to remove and recreate the script record.

Source control showed it was exactly the same record before and after.

My purpose was to test something --- if i update files via SDF all is well.  Not sure if updating via SDF after the advanced add would have resolved it.